# Angular pwa offline fallback url

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular

I have set up angular service PWA for my application and it seems to be working fine apart from offline.
Application is wrapped in asp.net Index.cshtml where it includes compiled files and therefore not use angular's index.html file.

I was trying to find a way to add a service worker handler for the angular service worker to fallback to offline.html in case it's offline.

It has been few days already and still no luck.

So my question is how do i set up fallback url for my angular service worker when the page is offline ?

Comment: I upvote your question, but also I think that your question missing some code, sorry